# Get Ground when 5V are available

Tags: logic-gates

This may sound like a basic task, but I am new to Electrical engineering.

I want to combine an QI Charging matt into my SmartHome. When my phone is charged by the mat a Green LED lights up. This LED is feed with 5V. I am using a window sensor to integrate this into my SmartHome. The sensor has a little magnet switch that pulls 5V to GND.

I now need to somehow get `GND` when the `5V` are supplied by the QI charger and I have no idea how.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a Smarthome, where is the link to the datasheet and what type of inputs has it got?

Comment: @Transistor All the products I use are production. There is no detailed datasheet available. As I already told, the Window monitor triggers when the `5V` signal is pulled to `GND` and the QI charger lights up an LED with 5V if something is charging. The two device do have a common ground.

Comment: When you "get" ground, what are you going to do with it? What do you want to "get" when the charger is not supplying 5 V?

Comment: I confused why people with thousands of answers each and probably several years of experience on stack exchange are trying to play around the question and pointing out grammatical mistakes while the answer is as simple as it can ever be. I mean what is the norm here? Do we want to solve each others problems or just try to train how to ask the best questions?

Comment: @AbdullahBaig I am a frequent user (asking and answering questiins) of Stackoverflow. I always try to answer all questions as long as they are somehow understandable without needing to know the end result. I am at best a hobby electrician and a non English speaker, so I don‘t know how to describe the problem the best ways.

Comment: @DavidGölzhäuser Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this circuit. Provide the 5V from the charger LED at **control signal** terminal. Connect the terminal **on/off switch** in the place of your window sensor.

The window sensor will get a GND when there is 5V at the charger.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed. It is working like a charm.

Comment: Keep experimenting dude. Way to go.